# NIFI Access Unknown: Certificate and Token not found

Tags: kubernetes, apache-nifi, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress, cert-manager

I want to deploy nifi on k8s and I use cert-manager. When I want to login, I get this:

Access Unknown: Certificate and Token not found.

[image: NiFi login]

I use these annotations in ingress:

```
  annotations:     
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: "HTTPS"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/upstream-vhost: "localhost:8443"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-redirect-from: "https://localhost:8443"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-redirect-to: "https://nifi.local"
    cert-manager.io/issuer: "my-nifi"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-body-size: "0"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-read-timeout: "600"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-send-timeout: "600"
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `cert-manager.io/issuer: "my-nifi"` annotation. I have set just these envs:

```yaml
...
        env:
        - name: NIFI_WEB_HTTPS_HOST
          value: 0.0.0.0 
        - name: INITIAL_ADMIN_IDENTITY
          value: "CN=admin, OU=NIFI"
        - name: NIFI_WEB_PROXY_HOST
          value: {{ .Values.nifi.ingress.host }},{{ include "nifi.fullname" . }}-{{ .Values.id }}:8443,{{ include "nifi.fullname" . }}-{{ .Values.id }}.{{ .Release.Namespace }}:8443
...
```

And I have set these annotations and tls field in Ingress:

```yaml
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: "HTTPS"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/upstream-vhost: "localhost:8443"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-redirect-from: "https://localhost:8443"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-redirect-to: "https://{{ .Values.nifi.ingress.host }}"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-body-size: "0"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-read-timeout: "600"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-send-timeout: "600" 

  tls:
  - hosts:
    - {{ .Values.nifi.ingress.host }}
    secretName: {{ include "nifi.fullname" . }}-0
```